# AWS CLI How to use tag filtering for the tag which contains multiple values when using ec2 describe-instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

AWS CLI provides a way for filtering by tag-key and tag-value in the following ways:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-key,Values=my_tag`

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-value,Values=my_tag_value`

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:my_tag,Values=my_tag_value`

but when tag contains multiple values, e.g. **my_tag**: *my_value1*, *my_value2*, *my_value3* it doesn't work.
When using any of the previous commands, it returns **only** those instances which contains tag with exactly this value. All other cases where the tag contains value along with other values are ignored.

How to achieve filtering like '*tag contains this value*' instead of '*tag is exactly this value*'?

P.C. I'll be using this approach in java application using aws-sdk, so I'm interested in aws-sdk api solution; I definitely don't want to filter a set of instances on my server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter tag values based on wildcards (either * or ? for multi or single character match respectively) or by listing them as comma separated values. So if I have three instances with a tag "t1" and different possible values across several instances, I can select them all with the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:t1,Values=*
```

You can also select subsets by using the wildcards or comma separated lists. Some examples are below, and the AWS reference page is [located here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html) for further information.

Match all values for the t1 tag that start with "myval" (Note the --query parameter is used in this example to just select the instance id, so we can quickly compare the results without scrolling all the JSON output):

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:t1,Values=myval* --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" --output text
```

Match a comma separated list of values:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:t1,Values=t1val1,t1val2
```

Match a single character wildcard:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:t1,Values=t1val?
```

Comment: Man, you saved my evening! I was sure that have tried this but seems that I foolished myself. Thanks a lot!